# Force scrollbar to display left side of content and not right side of contentn

Tags: qml, scrollbar

I've a TextArea within a ScrollView.

In this TextArea the text appends to be larger than width of the TextArea. Hence the use of ScrollView and scrollbars.

I would like the scrollbar to display the beginning of the line by default. But it is always showing the end of the line.

[image: screenshot of the scrollbar default position]

How can instruct the scrollbar to stay on its left by default ?

```
    Dialog {
        id: workDialog
        modality: Qt.ApplicationModal
        visible: false
        width: 900
        height: 700
        standardButtons: StandardButton.Abort
        

        ColumnLayout {

            anchors.fill: parent
            spacing: 5
            anchors.topMargin: 10
            anchors.rightMargin: 10
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            anchors.bottomMargin: 5

            Label {
                id: currentStatus
                Layout.preferredWidth: 600
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignLeft
                text: qsTr("Running...")
            }

            ScrollView {
                id: view
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.maximumHeight: 700
                clip: true
                TextArea {
                    id: resultText
                    //anchors.fill: parent
                    anchors.margins: 5
                    selectByMouse: true
                    selectByKeyboard: true
                    cursorVisible: true
                    readOnly: true
                    focus: true
                }

            ScrollBar.horizontal.policy: ScrollBar.AsNeeded
            ScrollBar.horizontal.position: 0
            ScrollBar.vertical.policy: ScrollBar.AsNeeded

            }
            
        }

        onRejected: {
            abortRequested = true
        }
    }
```

I tried by setting the `ScrollBar.horizontal.position: 0` but it has no effect.
Thanks

Comment: I tested your example and it worked fine for me, even after adding a long text. Also, try setting *0* to the **scrollbar position** after appending text.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. How can I access this property from outside the object itself ?

Comment: You can set the value of an object's attached attributes similarly to how you initialise it.(`view.ScrollBar.horizontal.position = 0`)